# Power BI How to ensure hovering tooltip consistency?

Tags: powerbi, hover, mousehover

Notice that, with the chart below, I can hover my mouse anywhere within the chart and it will 'trace' a vertical black line and highlight the intersection.
[image]

And when I select another value to filter chart, suddenly the behaviour changes. To highlight a particular point of interest, I have to put my mouse exactly at the point which makes it very hard as compared to having the previous vertical black line aiding with showing the points of interest.

Anyone notices this issue? Or is there any setting I need to check?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This is because the multiple lines do not have the same length of data.
For example, `'0 - Urgency Unassigned'` has only `505 data points` while `'3 - Low'` has the highest number of data points at `42,920`.

To resolve this, I have to ensure that the data points share the same exact values on the `X-axis` (which represents the `time`).

For example the `time` between `1` and `2` for `'0 - Urgency Unassigned'`, may have only `10` data points, while for `'3 - Low'`, the granularity is much higher at `60` data points.

By ensuring both to share the same exact data points such as `1`,`1.5` and `2`, which means only `3` data points between `time 1` and `2` for both `'0 - Urgency Unassigned'` and `'3 - Low'`, the tooltip can now be properly shown and the vertical black line appears.

[image]